# Как подружить Android x86 и Titanium Studio?

Tags: android, android-adb, virtualbox

Доброго времени суток.
Решил не мучаться с эмуляторами и реальным устройством и поставил себе Android x86 в Virtual Box.
Скорость отличная, не то что с эмулятором, но вот только Eclipse отлично запускает программы в VM, а Titanium Studio не хочет этого делать.
Читал builder.py из состава Titanium- для установки приложения на устройство используются цэмэдэшные вызовы adb.exe. Набрал сам в консоли отправляемые команды и увидел:

```
adb shell "cd /sdcard/"
device not found
```

Список устройств:

```
adb devices
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

Гугл сказал, что это из-за того, что устройство не является сертифицированным Google и поэтому adb не хочет с ним работать.
Нашел способ как обмануть гугл, если устройство реальное какое-нибудь китайское подключаемое через USB, но ведь виртуальная машина не через USB работает.
Настраивал кто-нибудь?

Comment: @Iranda примите, пожалуйста, мой ответ как верный- не могу сам это сделать.  
Пусть будет этот ответ для наследия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел решение.
Открываем папку со скриптами Titanium Mobile. У меня это

```
c:\Users\ReinRaus\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\
```

На всякий случай сохраняете резервную копию файла `builder.py`.
Открываем `builder.py` для редактирования.
Ищем вхождение текста

```
def build_and_run
```

После строки

```
if install:
```

дописываем

```
output= self.run_adb('devices')
dev_id, dev_type=output.split("\r\n")[1].split("\t")
if (dev_type== 'device'):
    self.device_args=['-s', dev_id]
```

В итоге получается

```
if install:
    output= self.run_adb('devices')
    dev_id, dev_type=output.split("\r\n")[1].split("\t")
    if (dev_type== 'device'):
        self.device_args=['-s', dev_id]
```

Ищем вхождение текста

```
Failed installing
```

Строку

```
elif not self.install:
```

меняем на

```
else:
```

Все. Наслаждаемся высокой скоростью виртуальной машины. Запуская проект как `Android Device`.
Данный способ не затрагивает никакой функциональности- он только исправляет пару недочетов кода.
Полное и обновляемое решение здесь:
http://reinraus.ru/wordpress/nastraivaem-titanium-studio-dlya-zapuska-prilozhenij-v-android-x86/

Comment: Почему-то галочки нет принять ответ.

Comment: Блин. Почему-то апнулось.  
Простите.  
Не хотел топать некропост, думал с модеркой он не топнется.  
Просто в блоге обновил запись указав, что делать, если нет python2.x в системе, или хочется, чтобы path вел на python 3.x

Comment: @ReinRaus А почему не пользуетесь Intel x86 Atom System Image? Эмулятор летает реактивно и не надо держать виртуалку... кстати сказать быстрее чем реальный девайс.

Comment: как альтернативу могу предложить AIDE для разработки (для фана)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, виртуалка пошустрее работает, чем Эмулятор+HAXM, есть конечно некоторые неудобства с интеграцией мыши, но когда привыкаешь, то и не замечаешь этого :)

Comment: @ReinRaus понятно. у меня субъективно быстрее эмулятор работает. но основная причина почему я отказался от виртуалки, это что эмуляторов я могу наделать и назапускать с разными андроидами, сейчас постоянно три штуки использую... и работает быстро и гладко (анимация в частности).